# Angular app running inside docker works when running on WSL2 ubuntu 20.04 and crash with Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli' on Ubuntu 18.04.2

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, angular8, package.json

I've been pulling my hair on this probleme for 10+ hours. I'm using docker to have the same behaviour on different machine but here I can't make it work.

I have created a docker-compose developpment stack on my WSL2 ubuntu 20.04.2 in order to launch an angular/flask/mysql app, it works fine.

I wanted to run this stack on a remote server I have in order to develop on this machine , kind of a test/dev server which is Ubuntu  18.04.2. The different os should not matter as I run everything inside dockers.

But when I run with 'sudo docker-compose up' on the Ubuntu 18.04.2 I have the following error related to my angular container:

```
angular-front | An unhandled exception occurred: Cannot find module '@angular/compiler-cli'
angular-front | Require stack:
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/angular_compiler_plugin.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/typescript.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/browser/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/dev-server/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/node-modules-architect-host.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/architect/node/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/architect-command.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/commands/serve-impl.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/export-ref.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular-devkit/schematics/tools/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/utilities/json-schema.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/models/command-runner.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/cli/index.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/init.js
angular-front | - /app/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng
angular-front | See "/tmp/ng-EEaQZX/angular-errors.log" for further details.
angular-front | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
angular-front | npm ERR! syscall spawn
angular-front | npm ERR! file sh
angular-front | npm ERR! errno ENOENT
angular-front | npm ERR! Scrapy@6.2.0 start: `ng serve`
angular-front | npm ERR! spawn ENOENT
angular-front | npm ERR!
angular-front | npm ERR! Failed at the Scrapy@6.2.0 start script.
angular-front | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
angular-front |
angular-front | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
angular-front | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-09-15T10_27_31_226Z-debug.log
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml, the service 'angular' is the one we might need to focus on:

```
# Use root/example as user/password credentials
version: '3.1'

services:

  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: !!!
      MYSQL_DATABASE: !!!!!!!!!
      MYSQL_USER: !!!!!!!
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: !!!!!!
    container_name: database_db
    ports:
    - "3307:3306"
  python:
    container_name: python-back
    build:
      context: ./myappback
    command: nodemon -L -e js,py --exec python3 -m flask run --host=0.0.0.0
    ports:
     - "5000:5000"
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./myappback:/app
  angular:
    container_name: angular-front
    build:
      context: ./myappfront
      dockerfile: dockerfile_dev
    ports:
     - "4200:4200"
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
     - ./myappfront:/app
     - /app/node_modules
```

Here is the dockerfile_dev that is used to build the angular app:

```
FROM node:12.14.1

WORKDIR /app
RUN mkdir node_modules
COPY package.json ./

RUN ls
RUN ls /app
RUN npm install -g --unsafe-perm @angular/cli@8.3.29  nodemon 
RUN ng --version
RUN npm install 

EXPOSE 4200 49153

RUN ng --version
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

I tried to debug the package version with "ng --version" and everything is similar on both servers:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 8.3.29
Node: 12.14.1
OS: linux x64
Angular: 8.2.14
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic
... router, service-worker

Package                           Version
-----------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect         0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-angular     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer   0.803.29
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.803.29
@angular-devkit/core              8.3.29
@angular-devkit/schematics        8.3.29
@angular/cdk                      8.2.3
@angular/cli                      8.3.29
@angular/flex-layout              8.0.0-beta.27
@angular/material                 8.2.3
@angular/pwa                      0.803.29
@ngtools/webpack                  8.3.29
@schematics/angular               8.3.29
@schematics/update                0.803.29
rxjs                              6.5.5
typescript                        3.5.3
webpack                           4.39.2
```

I use Angular 8 cause I have not migrated yet to the latest version.

Here is also my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "Scrapy",
  "version": "6.2.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "build_test": "ng build --configuration=test",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "1.0.0",
    "@amcharts/amcharts4": "^4.10.18",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "0.803.29",
    "@angular/animations": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^8.0.0-beta.27",
    "@angular/forms": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "0.803.29",
    "@angular/router": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "8.2.14",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^11.0.1",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^4.0.0",
    "@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to": "^3.0.1",
    "angular-calendar": "~0.28.0",
    "angular-sortablejs": "^2.7.0",
    "chart.js": "~2.9.3",
    "chart.piecelabel.js": "~0.15.0",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "chartjs-plugin-annotation": "^0.5.7",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highlight.js": "^11.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "lodash-es": "~4.17.15",
    "material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
    "moment": "~2.24.0",
    "ngx-file-drop": "^8.0.8",
    "ngx-quill": "~7.3.9",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "normalize.css": "~8.0.1",
    "quill": "~1.3.7",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.3",
    "rxjs-compat": "~6.5.3",
    "screenfull": "~5.0.0",
    "simplebar": "5.0.7",
    "smoothscroll-polyfill": "^0.4.4",
    "sortablejs": "~1.10.1",
    "stream": "0.0.2",
    "vis-data": "^6.5.3",
    "vis-network": "^7.6.10",
    "vis-util": "^4.1.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "8.2.14",
    "@types/chart.js": "~2.9.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.4.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.8",
    "@types/lodash-es": "~4.17.3",
    "@types/node": "~12.12.9",
    "codelyzer": "~5.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.5.2",
    "tslint": "~5.20.1",
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Maybe it's an issue between angular/cli version and angular/compiler-cli ?

Any angular expert could help me debug this ? I have tried several things

- running "npm install -g" and "npm install" in the angular dockerfile
- "npm install -g @angular/compiler-cli" in dockerfile_dev
- check everything ten times, rebuild images of the angular

Comment: You might have an outdated `node_modules`. The files from the build-step are only copied into the volume when it's first created. On later runs/start it will reuse the old volume.

Comment: I see thanks, the volume to node_modules is actually bound to nothing on the server, it's a trick to tell docker "share all src in /app except node_modules", but I'll take a look closer at it

Comment: Yeah, the issue with that is the files created during the build-step of the container are not visible inside the container. Every time you make some changes to your dependencies you need to delete the volume and rebuild the container. Or re-run `npm install` inside the container once it's up an running to update the content of the volume.

Answer (score 0):

the line

```
angular-front | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

is suggesting that it's not a problem with npm,but rather something else

I ran into something like this and after alot of search I found out the cause was that the server ran out of memory(there was only 4 GB of ram).
I ended up adding more swap area to solve the problem.

recently I found another solution on AWS  (ECR ->elastic container registry:whre you build your container and push the docker container to AWS ECR)

Hope this could od any help to you .

Comment: Thanks for the reply, my local WSL ubuntu has less RAM that the remote server that has 8Gb so not sure it's the problem. I'll check out AWS ECR thank you